# Java HotSpot(TM) Embedded Client VM warning: Can't detect initial thread stack location: find_vma failed

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I am using `raspberry pi` and `Linux Kernel` into it. After `rootfs` mounted I have got the following error message when the file `/etc/init.d/rcS` got execute.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Embedded Client VM warning: Can't detect initial thread stack location: find_vma failed 
Hello World Java is executing fine //It is the output of HelloWorld
```

Here is my `/etc/init.d/rcS` file contains

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/arm/jli/
cd /etc/sample_javaTest
exec java HelloWorld
```

My question is my java code running fine then why the warning occur??

Please correct me if I doing any thing wrong or in a incorrect way.

Thank you